# Spring data and maven error

Tags: maven, spring-boot, slf4j

Can someone help me ? I'm using spring boot with spring data and
when a put this line in my pom.xml

Line:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId> org.springframework.data </groupId> 
    <artifactId> spring-data-commons-core </artifactId> 
    <version> 1.4.1.RELEASE </version> 
</dependency>
```

Error:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
```

Tried to solve it by manually changing the sl4j in my pom, but it didn't work.
Don't know why? any thoughts?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.alura.listavip</groupId>
<artifactId>listavip</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Edit: if its helpful, here's my dependency tree

```
    n+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.39:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile

<code>
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.39:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
```

Comment: Where did you change the slf4j version ? I can't see it in your pom.xml.

Comment: Why are ou using such an old version? The correct version is already included from the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: @RITZXAVI i just put

`< dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>`

didint solve thought.

Comment: I still don't see an slf4j dependency added explicitly (not transitive) in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

I just changed the version of my spring data in my pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId> org.springframework.data </groupId>
    <artifactId> spring-data-jpa </artifactId>
    <version> 1.10.5.RELEASE </version>
</dependency>
```